# JetpackCompose OutlinedTextField cant resize the input inside textfield

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

My field looks like this. As you can see from the image, there is some kind of space between the border and the actual input field, what is causing this and how can I resize it. I have tried changing size of text but it doesn't change the size of the input. It always keeps some kind of space on top or bot. Resizing the height of the textfield itself it shows the full input but that doesn't work for me because there is still space on top and bot.

[image]

Comment: please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which leads to this behaviour.

Comment: It's the default element that jetpack compose provides. Nothing special to it just the question is how to resize the input fild inside it and why is there spacing on top and bot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `defaultMinSize` with modifier ... and pass `minHeight` as much as you want

```
        OutlinedTextField(
                      value = "Some Value",
                      onValueChange = {

                      },
                      modifier = Modifier.defaultMinSize(minHeight = 280.dp),
                 )
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple, I was setting the height but it wasn't changing, but by setting the defaultMinSize it worked. Thank you!